# How to instantiate and populate a Scala Stream in Java?

Tags: java, scala

I have a Scala function `foo(bs : Stream[Bar]) : Bat` that I need to call from Java code. How do I create the "bs" Stream (`Stream[Bar]`) in Java and lazily generate its Bar objects?

Comment: Where does that stream comes from? Do you have it in a Java Collection, will you get it through event, what? Without knowing that, it is impossible to assert what would be the best way about it.

Comment: In my real-world problem, I have a Java Vector. I would be interested in understanding what / why I would do something different if it were generated from an event.

Comment: For your problem @Travis answer is the way to go. Generating from an event is more difficult -- a good example is Scala's sys.process library, which can generate a `Stream` from the `OutputStream` of a running process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what needs to be in the stream, it might be easiest to create a `java.util.Iterator` and then convert this to a `Stream` via a `scala.collection.Iterator`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream;

...

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

\\ Fill the list somehow...

Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

Stream<String> stream = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(it)
                                      .asScala().toStream();
```

The iterator doesn't have to come from a collection, of course—we can just as easily create an infinite stream by implementing our own iterator:

```
Stream<String> stream = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(
  new Iterator<String>() {
    int i = 0;
    public boolean hasNext() { return true; }
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    public String next() { return Integer.toString(i++); }
  }
).asScala().toStream();
```

It's not as pretty as something like `Stream.iterate(0)(_ + 1).map(_.toString)`, but it works.

Answer (score 10):

The best way is to use one of the factories available on `Stream` object companion. For the most useful of them, you'll need to implement `Function1` as well, which can be done by extending `AbstractFunction1`.

Here's an example:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;

public class Ex {
    public Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(0, new Increment());
}

class Increment extends AbstractFunction1<Integer, Integer> {
    public Integer apply(Integer v1) {
        return v1 + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted @Travis' answer because it is the simplest answer to my particular problem, but this answer is very helpful for the more general case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
scala.collection.immutable.Stream bs = new scala.collection.immutable.Stream()
```

?

Comment: I've edited the question to try to make it clear that I am looking for a complete example of Java-based Stream generation (not just instantiation)

Answer (score 0):

I know you were looking for scala stream but there is functional java too: http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Stream.html